# Async JQuery AJAX post locks the page in asp.net

Tags: jquery, ajax

I got couple of JQuery.ajax posts that i need to get some data back.

They are all async:true; but they lock the page.I can't click other links till they end up loading.

i am using .net framework 4.5.

Could not find a solution googling...

Comment: showing some code (javascript) would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set `async:true` then the requests will be asynchronous. Since you have mentioned .NET 4.5, I suppose that you are using ASP.NET on the server. If the endpoint you are hitting with those AJAX requests is using sessions, those requests will be queued and executed sequentially instead of in parallel because in ASP.NET the session is not thread safe and it simply doesn't allow you to have concurrent requests from the same session. But this is a server side issue which shouldn't be *locking* the browser and preventing you from clicking on other links until the requests are executing.

Maybe there's some other script on your page which is responsible for this behavior. Unfortunately there's not enough information in your question to be able to determine it.